# Sort unsorted data by matching columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm currently working on a spreadsheet that contains monthly data about a quantity of logins from users. This data is extrapolated from a monitoring program which provides us with each user's username, and the number of logins sorted. It looks something like as follows, but much lengthier and with actual usernames:

```
USER       LOGINS (Feb)
a          10
b          7
c          6
d          3
e          1
```

However, as the report was generated using the data from a specific month, the next month's data was provided in a different order due to user's activity changing. The next month looks something like this.

```
USER       LOGINS (March)
e          13
b          9
d          4
c          3
a          2
```

Now, I'd like to collect all this data into one spreedsheet. Problem is that I need all the users to be ordered in one way (the way the first month/table was) and so I also need the subsequent data to be ordered the same way.

The table above would need to be changed to this. Note that the ordering of this table is based off of the first one and isn't actually alphabetical that's just how i've expressed the data:

```
USER       LOGINS (March)
a          2
b          9
c          3
d          4
e          13
```

Is there any way to do this in excel?

Comment: Good question. This data can potentially include 0 and also new entries, but the new entries can be handled manually.

Comment: ,, put comments is good practice,,but unable to understand the reason behind this one,,, any ways I think you need VBA macro to Auto Sort enter data!!

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this in Excel, with or without VBA. But you don't really provide enough information about the process to provide meaningful assistance. How does the information get into Excel? I'd intercept it at that point, do the sorting, and then put it into the worksheet.  A Pivot Table might be useful, perhaps using Power Query.